# PDO Insert does not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I have a problem I can not make a request prepared by PDO every time it returns false to me.

```
   $table = 'paroles'; 
   $array = array(
        'timestamp' => 'VALEUR',
        'cle' => 'VALEUR',
        'titre' => 'VALEUR',
        'paroles' => 'VALEUR',
        'titre_trad' => 'VALEUR',
        'paroles_trad' => 'VALEUR'
    );
     
    $values = '';$datas = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $values = $values.$key.',';
        $datas = $datas.':'.$key.',';
    }
    $values = trim($values, ',');
    $datas = trim($datas, ',');
     
    $requestconstr = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.'('.$values.') VALUES('.$datas.')';
     
    $sth = $this->_db->prepare($requestconstr);
     
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $sth->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
    }
     
    if($sth->execute()){
        return true;
    }else return false;

    // PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => INSERT INTO paroles(timestamp,cle,titre,paroles,titre_trad,paroles_trad) VALUES(:timestamp,:cle,:titre,:paroles,:titre_trad,:paroles_trad) )
```

Comment: Try wrapping your statement in a try/catch - see what PDO is telling you when it's attempting to INSERT.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: @Script47 - he's concatenating a list of keys and values together in the `foreach`, and then just adding that into the SQL statement.

Comment: Try `foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {` instead, bindParam needs a reference to the value you are binding it to.

Comment: @Script47 - he's creating a prepared statement. `$values` ends up with a comma-separated list of fieldnames, and `$data` gets a list of placeholders.

Comment: @andrewsi ah, that's why. I've never really looked in to colon placeholders so that just went straight over my head. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are building the query properly, but regardless, this is probably a cleaner way to do it, and the check at the end should give you some more information on what is going wrong:

```
$params = array_map(function($item) { return ":" . $item; }, array_keys($array));
$placeholders = implode(",", $params);
$columns = implode(",", array_keys($array));

$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$columns}) VALUES ({$placeholders})";

$bind = array_combine($params, array_values($array));
$sth = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
if ($sth->execute($bind)) {
    return true;
} else {
    die(print_r($this->_db->errorInfo(), true));
}
```